# Disable warning: "There is a user sharing this computer."

Tags: sharing, shutdown, restart

I have a Mac used as a test server and it restarts daily automatically. Occasionally we connect to it to grab files, but if we forget to disconnect, the Mac fails to restart because it waits for confirmation for this dialog:

[image: Imgur]

"There is a user sharing this computer. If you restart they will be disconnected."

Is there a way to disable this confirmation and make sure the Mac always restarts regardless of who is connected?

Comment: How do you trigger the automatic daily restart?

Comment: @DanielLawson System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Schedule

Comment: What about creating an automator task that fires when the window opens, and all it does is hit restart?

Comment: This is still a problem and it is desirable to disable in 2022 in macOS 12.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `launchd` to execute `/sbin/shutdown -r now` as root at the time you want to restart.

I'm not able to expand this into step-by-step directions right now, but this might be helpful and if you don't get a more thorough answer first, I can come back and expand this hint in a fuller set of directions later this week.

Comment: This is not a sufficient solution when doing things like system updates. We're still in need of a method to alter the system .plist or some such other preference(s) in 2022 with macOS 12.x.